# How to merge two Hibernate Queries?

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, hql

I need to merge results from two different queries in order to sort the results by dateCreated.

I would like to do:

```
def query = """ 
  select user from 
   (select v.user, v.dateCreated from Vote as v where v.item=:item order by v.dateCreated desc) as myvotes, 
   (select c.user, c.dateCreated from Comment as c where c.item=:item order by c.dateCreated desc) as mycomments

def item = // some item
tmpUsers = Message.executeQuery (query, [item: item])
```

How do I have to merge two queries?

Comment: Query is incomplete? What is `u`?

Comment: Is Vote anyway related to Comment?

Comment: Have a look at the update.

Comment: @dmahapatro Vote is not related to Comment.

Comment: ok, the answer is valid too for that case. Let know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def index() {
        def query1 = """ 
                    select new Map(v.user as user, v.dtCreated as dtCreated) from Vote as v where v.item = :item
                    """
        def query2 = """ 
                    select new Map(c.user as user, c.dtCreated as dtCreated) from Comment as c where c.item = :item
                    """                 

        def result1 = Vote.executeQuery(query1, [item: 'A'])
        def result2 = Comment.executeQuery(query2, [item: 'A'])

        def mergedList = ([] << result1 << result2)?.flatten()?.sort{a,b -> b.dtCreated <=> a.dtCreated}
        render mergedList as grails.converters.JSON
    }
```

I agree there is no proper UNION in HQL. If `Vote` is no way connected to `Comment` then the above implementation (2 simple queries instead of 1 complex one)would provide what is expected.

Assumption,

```
class Vote {
    String item
    Date dtCreated
    String user
}

class Comment {
    String item
    Date dtCreated
    String user
}

//Bootstrap
def vote1 = new Vote(item: "A", dtCreated: new Date(), user: 'user1')
def vote2 = new Vote(item: "A", dtCreated: new Date() + 1, user: 'user2')
def vote3 = new Vote(item: "A", dtCreated: new Date() + 2, user: 'user3')

def comment1 = new Comment(item: "A", dtCreated: new Date(), user: 'user4')
def comment2 = new Comment(item: "A", dtCreated: new Date() - 4, user: 'user5')
def comment3 = new Comment(item: "A", dtCreated: new Date() - 6, user: 'user6')

[vote1, vote2, vote3, comment1, comment2, comment3]*.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

//Output Json:
[
    {
        "dtCreated": "2013-06-23T13:49:24Z",
        "user": "user3"
    },
    {
        "dtCreated": "2013-06-22T13:49:24Z",
        "user": "user2"
    },
    {
        "dtCreated": "2013-06-21T13:49:24Z",
        "user": "user4"
    },
    {
        "dtCreated": "2013-06-21T13:49:24Z",
        "user": "user1"
    },
    {
        "dtCreated": "2013-06-17T13:49:24Z",
        "user": "user5"
    },
    {
        "dtCreated": "2013-06-15T13:49:24Z",
        "user": "user6"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it hibernate-pojo style where you fetch both a collection of Vote and Comment object and merge them in java. For example:

```
List<User> mergedUsers = new LinkedList<User>();

List<Vote> votes = voteDAO.getVotes();
List<Comment> comments = commentDAO.getComments();

for(Vote vote : votes) mergedUsers.add(new User(vote));
for(Comment comment : comments) mergedUsers.add(new User(comment));
```

Or you can issue a native jdbc query using SQL "UNION" keyword and map the result into whatever your result object (User object?)

Comment: Can you give an example off how to merge them?